# How to handle exceptions properly in custom Spring security 3.0 authentication?

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm developing a REST service based in tokens. When an user goes to ../rest/authenticate with the user and password via curl, gets a valid token in order to use the whole API.

My problem appears when the user forgets to insert the username, the password or the token in the other methods because i've not managed to handle the Authentication exceptions as I want.

I cand handle the exceptions but tomcat gets the response and inserts some html that I don't expect.

[image: curl]

This is the typical response of tomcat.
[image: tomcat]

Is it possible to receive a response like 200 OK which don't have this html code?

At the momment, this is my config:

## AuthenticationProcessingFilter

Decides if the url is secured or not. If has to be secured, calls the authentication manager in order to validate it. If receives an authentication exceptions calls the AuthenticationEntryPoint

```
public class AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter extends GenericFilterBean {

    private final Collection<String> nonTokenAuthUrls = Lists.newArrayList("/rest","/rest/authenticate");

    TokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager;
    RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;

    public AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter(TokenAuthenticationManager tokenAuthenticationManager, RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint) {
        this.tokenAuthenticationManager = tokenAuthenticationManager;
        this.restAuthenticationEntryPoint = restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest)request;
        HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse)response;
        try{
            if(!nonTokenAuthUrls.contains(httpRequest.getRequestURI())){ //Auth by token
                 String hash = httpRequest.getHeader("token");
                 UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(hash, null);
                 authentication.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails((HttpServletRequest) request));
                 SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(tokenAuthenticationManager.authenticate(authentication));
            }
            response.reset();
            chain.doFilter(request, response); 
        }catch(AuthenticationException authenticationException){
            SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
            restAuthenticationEntryPoint.commence(httpRequest, httpResponse, authenticationException);
        }
    }
```

## AuthenticationManager

```
public class TokenAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager{

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @Autowired
    TokenService tokenService;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        Object hash = authentication.getPrincipal();
        if(hash == null)
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Token is required");
        User user = tokenService.getUserFromTokenHash((String)hash); 
        if(user == null)
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Non-existent token");
        if(!tokenService.validate((String)hash)) 
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Expired Token");
        org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User userDetails = new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword(), getUserGrantedAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, user.getPassword(), getUserGrantedAuthorities(user.getRoles()));
    }
```

## AuthenticationEntryPoint

This class works OK. The code received is 401 unauthorized but the message is in the tomcat html

public class RestAuthenticationEntryPoint implements AuthenticationEntryPoint {

```
@Override
public void commence(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException authenticationException) throws IOException, ServletException {
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    response.sendError( HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED, authenticationException.getMessage() );
    response.getOutputStream().println("{ \"error\": \"" + authenticationException.getMessage() + "\" }");
}
```

}

The RestAccessDeniedHanler is not called either. It's difficult becasue there are a lot of classes that have to be implemented.

I reviewed some post in stackoverflow and other websites and my approach consist on catching the exceptions in the AuthenticationProcessingFilter and call the AuthenticationEntryPoint manually. I decided to do that becasue I've tried to configure this in the applicationContext-security.xml with no success.

## appliacionContext-security.xml

```
<b:bean id="restAuthenticationEntryPoint" class="...web.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" /> 

<b:bean id="tokenAuthenticationManager" class="...dp.web.security.TokenAuthenticationManager"/>

<b:bean id="AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" class="...web.security.AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter">
    <b:constructor-arg type="...dp.web.security.TokenAuthenticationManager" ref="tokenAuthenticationManager"></b:constructor-arg>
    <b:constructor-arg type="...dp.web.security.RestAuthenticationEntryPoint" ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint"></b:constructor-arg>
</b:bean>

<b:bean id="accessDeniedHandler" class="...dp.web.security.RestAccessDeniedHandler">
</b:bean>

<http realm="Protected REST API" pattern="/rest/**" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" create-session="stateless"  entry-point-ref="restAuthenticationEntryPoint">
    <custom-filter ref="AuthenticationTokenProcessingFilter" position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler"/>
</http>
```

how can I send a clean response with the error code and a message?

Answer (score 2):

You can use error-pages in your web.xml to intercept Tomcat's error page.  For example,

```
<error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/404</location>
</error-page>
```

Now you use RequestMapping to map /404 to a page that returns your JSON response without any HTML:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/404", method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT, RequestMethod.DELETE})
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> handle404() {

    HttpStatus status = null;
    ResponseStatus responseStatus = new ResponseStatus("404", "Wrong path to resource.");
    status = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND;

    ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus> response = new ResponseEntity<ResponseStatus>(responseStatus, status);

    return response;
}
```

Which will simply return a JSON object called Response Status that contains an error code and error message as fields.

Comment: I didn't mention that in my app there are two http. One for dp/rest which is accessed without web browser and /dp which has the view (jsp pages) to be accessed with the web browser. Is this only possible through the web.xml? Because in the web.xml i already have <error-code>404.. <location>/errors/notfound.jsp.. is it possible to separate the errors?

Comment: If you know what the Exception is, you can define ExceptionHandlers in Spring to do whatever you want when an exception gets thrown.  That sounds like what you are looking for.  Let me know if you need more information... but a good place to start looking is here: http://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc